# ubuntu 12.04 LTS won't install

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8

I have a windows 8 laptop, 64 bit OS, x64 based processor. I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS matching all of these specs. I go to boot it, and I hit "install Ubuntu" but it just gives me a blank screen. I let it sit for 10 minutes, but it didn't change, so I tried it again.
Same result. I tried running Ubuntu without installing and it still didn't work. Any suggestions?? And am I supposed to run wubi.exe file??

Answer (score 0):

when you have the options to "install ubuntu" and "try ubuntu" select the option you want and hit <kbd>e</kbd>. now with the arrow keys navigate to the part where it seays `quiet splash` and change it `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot. you might have to do the same when you have installed ubuntu.

Comment: oh aparently this is only valid for Nvidea video cards.